# linq group by with count

Tags: linq

Im trying to write query in linq

```
Select UserId, UserNumber 
FROM User
where UserNumber in
(Select UserNumber
        FROM User
        group by UserNumber
        having Count(UserId) = 1)
```

Aby hints ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var query = from u in User
            group u by u.UserNumber into usergroup
            where usergroup.Count() == 1
            from item in usergroup
            select new { item.UserId,item.UserNumber };
```

Comment: Does this generate a single query?  Or 1 query per group?

Comment: it's a single query, when `User` is actually something like `dbContext.Users`

Answer (score 0):

If subqueries are your thing, you could do it this way.

```
var subquery =
  from u in User
  group u by u.UserNumber into g
  where g.Count() = 1
  select g.Key;

var query =
  from u in User
  where subquery.Any(num => num == u.UserNumber)
  select u;
```